# Proguard Mapping file: meaning of n:n (0:0 and 1:1)

Tags: java, android, proguard

I've a proguard mapping file that contain things like:

```
   androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl -> androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl:
        androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable mParcel -> a
        1:1:void androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelParcel.<init>(android.os.Parcel):0:0 -> <init>
        1:1:void <init>(android.os.Parcel):0 -> <init>
        2:2:java.lang.String androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelParcel.readString():0:0 -> <init>
...
        9:9:void androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel.writeVersionedParcelable(androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable):0:0 -> writeToParcel
        9:9:void writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel,int):0 -> writeToParcel
        10:10:void androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel.writeToParcel(androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable,androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel):0:0 -> writeToParcel
        10:10:void androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel.writeVersionedParcelable(androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable):0 -> writeToParcel
        10:10:void writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel,int):0 -> writeToParcel
```

Questions:

1. I cannot find the doc of the mapping file format. Is there any ?
2. What's the meaning of 1:1, 2:2 etc ?
3. The last few line seems to rename the method to the exact same name. In some cases they even have the same signature. How is that possible ?
4. At the end of the function name, after the closing ), sometime there is :0:0 or :0. What does it mean ?

Comment: My guess is that it's a class key; the numbers after the methods seem to match up with the method parameters, and `0` looks like it corresponds to Android built-in classes, which are not obfuscated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: the "10:10" for instance, doesn't seems to match anything related to parameters ... The only thing I understand is that all the 10:10 or 9:9 method are obfuscated with the same name. It's surprising mapping file format seems to have no doc ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no documentation explaining mapping.txt but if you see the mapping.txt file and match these numbers with your source class file on which obfuscation is done, you will find that these numbers are line numbers of source file

> and **n:n** tells **start:end** of that method's code.

I could tell this by comparing my mapping file comparing with source. These could be other explanation as well.